# Answer appears multiple times in first answer review queue

Tags: bug, review, timeline

I just came accross an answer that seemingly appeared multiple times in the same review queue. If I trust the timeline it was three times. First reviewed by two people, then again by one who already reviewed it the first time and then another time by a third member:

[image]

Link to timeline: https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/449274/timeline. You can also see that in the history: https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/history (requires 10k on the site.)

Not sure if I just get this wrong, if it is a feature (maybe because of the rollback) or a bug?